# Looking for Bacterial/Infectious Diseases Dataset

Tags: data-request, medical

Does anyone know of a dataset of bacteria-infectiousness-symptoms or something of the sort? Thanks! Looking to classify infectiousness (ie. infectious/not infectious) via bacterial genomic sequencing/metadata.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs in the OpenData SE :)

Comment: Better migrate than close.